# ubuntu nodejs syntax error Syntax Error: Unexpected token `

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I went through the process of installing the **VolumioUI** on **Ubuntu** 
as explained in [this link.](https://volumio.github.io/docs/Development_How_To/Set_up_a_development_environment.html)

and I get:

```
/Volumio2-UI$ gulp serve --theme="volumio"

/home/yossi/elia/Volumio2-UI/gulp/build.js:127
      fs.readFileSync(`${conf.paths.src}/app/themes/${themeSelected}/assets/va
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /home/yossi/elia/Volumio2-UI/gulpfile.js:19:3
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yossi/elia/Volumio2-UI/gulpfile.js:18:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I did the same process on **MAC** with no problems.

This is very strange since it complains about a syntax error.

if I change it to ' than it works fine, the problem is that the code is full of this error.

Can I config NodeJs to treat ` as ' 
?

Note: I was able to solve it by search-and-replace, but I leave this question open because I would like to know if it can be solved with a config

```
$ node --version
v0.10.25
```

Comment: Do you have node.js 4.8.4 or higher running on your Ubuntu machine (`node --version`)? http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-template-literals

Comment: v0.10.25 I guess this explains the issue...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backticks are part of the new syntax introduced in the latest version of Javascript (ES6).

The problem occurs, because you have a (very) old version of node, which does not implement this new syntax. Probably, you have node v.0.10 instead of node v.7

The solution is to upgrade node.js.

Here is how (Ubuntu 14), see https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

This is the solucion with the problem for Invalid or unexpected token when you use npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are different from single quotes, they aren't interchangeable by means of setting a configuration option somewhere.

You need a relatively recent Node.js version (v4.4.2 or up, I think) that supports the backtick ([*"template literal"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) syntax.